# JavaScript animation clingy circles

Tags: javascript, css, animation, canvas, geometry

On my canvas animation, I have a problem where my circles are getting drawn "without the metaphorical pen" lifting from the canvas.

I need a way to stop the function and just draw one circle than another one.

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4nQCa/) (Warning: uses 100% of one logical processor core/thread).

**JavaScript:**

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var size = 19;
var size_two = 19;

function start(){
    requestAnimationFrame(start);
    size++;
    context.arc(95, 85, size, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    context.stroke();
}

function othercircle(){
    requestAnimationFrame(othercircle);
    size_two++; 
    context.arc(500, 300, size_two, 0, 3*Math.PI);
}

start();
othercircle();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers are good, but I wanted to highlight why your unwanted line is appearing.

**Your unwanted connecting line**

The unwanted connecting line is created because you must call context.beginPath() before drawing each arc.  If you don't call begainPath the browser assumes you want to connect the 2 circle paths.

```
context.beginPath()
context.arc(95, 85, size, 0, 2*Math.PI);
context.stroke();

context.beginPath();
context.arc(200, 200, size_two, 0, 3*Math.PI);
context.stroke();
```

**Just a couple more notes**

- Your `othercircle` is drawing an arc that's 3 * PI.  2*PI is a complete circle and any value above 2*PI will not add to the circle.
- If it was your intent to draw an expanding stroke-circle, then you should clear the canvas at the start of each animation loop (before drawing the expanded circles).
- One requestAnimationFrame is enough.  You can put both your circle and your othercircle code in one requestAnimationFrame.

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/62mFF/

```
var sizeCounter=19;      
var maxSizeCounter=60;
var size = sizeCounter;
var maxSize=40;
var size_two = sizeCounter;
var maxSizeTwo=60;

function start(){

  if(sizeCounter<maxSizeCounter){   requestAnimationFrame(start); }

  // clear the canvas if you want strokes instead of filled circles
  context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

  context.beginPath()
  context.arc(95, 85, size, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  context.stroke();
  if(size<maxSize){ size++; }

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(200, 200, size_two, 0, 3*Math.PI);
  context.stroke();
  if(size_two<maxSizeTwo){ size_two++; }

  sizeCounter++;

}

start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Then use a condition to stop the recursive call, or just omit `size++` and `size_two++` from your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your functions don't have all the information for a complete circle, thus the line between the two circles. Below will make two circles without the line between them.

```
function start(){
  requestAnimationFrame(start);
  size++;

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(95, 85, size, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
}

function othercircle(){
  requestAnimationFrame(othercircle);
  size_two++; 

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(500, 300, size_two, 0, 3*Math.PI);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
}
```

Here is an updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bbFfn/)

Comment: I am glad it solved your problem. Don't forget to mark this one as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/4nQCa/5

I think it's simpler to go object in your case : define a Circle class that will update with time and draw itself :

```
/// Circle class.
//  has update(dt) and draw as public method.
function Circle(x, y, initSize, endSize, duration, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.size = initSize;
    this.endSize = endSize;
    this.color = color;
    this.speed = (endSize - initSize) / duration;
    this.update = function (dt) {
        if (this.speed == 0) return;
        this.size += dt * this.speed;
        if (this.size > this.endSize) {
            this.size = this.endSize;
            this.speed = 0;
        }
    }
    this.draw = function () {
        context.beginPath();
        context.strokeStyle = this.color;
        context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        context.stroke();
    }
}
```

then hold all your animated objects within an array

```
  var scene=[];
```

And have the objects animated/drawn :

```
function animate() {
    // keep alive
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    //  handle time
    var callTime = Date.now();
    var dt = callTime - lastTime;
    lastTime = callTime;
    // clear screen
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    context.fillText('Click anywhere !',40, 80);
    // draw
    for (var i = 0; i < scene.length; i++) {
        var thisObject = scene[i];
        thisObject.draw();
    }
    // update
    for (var i = 0; i < scene.length; i++) {
        var thisObject = scene[i];
        thisObject.update(dt);
    }

}
var lastTime = Date.now();

animate();
```

With this scheme it's easy to add/remove objects. For instance to add circles on mouse click :

```
addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    var x = e.clientX,
        y = e.clientY;
    var color = 'hsl(' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 360) + ',80%, 85%)';
    var newCircle = new Circle(x, y, 20, 100, 1000, color);
    scene.push(newCircle);
});
```